# Why is simple html and css working differently in an Angular 2 project vs vanilla html website

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

The below html/css does not work the same in a new Angular project created w/ Angular CLI using 'ng new ProjectName'. I add the CSS to app.component.css or styles.css and the html to app.component.html. In the Angular version it is as if it ignores my height on the body. The header does not stay fixed when scrolling in either the sidenav or content section.

**UPDATE:** I noticed when removing the app-root tag from the Angular version everything works. Why is app-root causing this not to work.

**Working HTML/CSS:**

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#row2 {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 0 0;
}
.header {
  height: 64px;
    background-color: red;
}
.sidenav {
  flex: 0 0 250px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
.main-content {
  flex: 1 0 0;
  background-color: blue;
}
.sidenav, .main-content {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div id="row1">
    <div class="header"></div>
</div>
<div id="row2">
    <div class="sidenav">        Testing<br/>Testing<br/>Testing<br/>Testing<br/>Testing<br/>Testing<br/>Testing<br/>Testing<br/>Testing<br/>Testing<br/>Testing<br/>Testing<br/>Testing<br/>Testing<br/>Testing<br/>Testing<br/>Testing<br/>Testing<br/>Testing<br/>Testing<br/>Testing<br/>Testing<br/>Testing<br/>Testing<br/>Testing<br/>Testing<br/>
    </div>
    <div class="main-content">
        Testing<br/>Testing<br/>Testing<br/>Testing<br/>Testing<br/>Testing<br/>Testing<br/>Testing<br/>Testing<br/>Testing<br/>Testing<br/>Testing<br/>Testing<br/>Testing<br/>Testing<br/>Testing<br/>Testing<br/>Testing<br/>Testing<br/>Testing<br/>Testing<br/>Testing<br/>Testing<br/>Testing<br/>Testing<br/>Testing<br/>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Here is the Angular 2 output:** (Please note that in the css files I add the css just like in the above snippet, Angular adds the ngcontent tags to it and the additional flex styles are just added from chrome developer tools)

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#row2[_ngcontent-c0] {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
      -ms-flex: 1 0 0px;
          flex: 1 0 0;
}
.header[_ngcontent-c0] {
  height: 64px;
}
.sidenav[_ngcontent-c0] {
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
      -ms-flex: 0 0 250px;
          flex: 0 0 250px;
}
.main-content[_ngcontent-c0] {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
      -ms-flex: 1 0 0px;
          flex: 1 0 0;
}
.sidenav[_ngcontent-c0], .main-content[_ngcontent-c0] {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<html><head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>FlexTest</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  </head>
<body>
  <app-root _nghost-c0="" ng-version="4.0.3">
  <div _ngcontent-c0="" id="row1">
  <div _ngcontent-c0="" class="header">HEADER</div>
</div>
<div _ngcontent-c0="" id="row2">
  <div _ngcontent-c0="" class="sidenav">
    Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">
        Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">
            Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">
  </div>
  <div _ngcontent-c0="" class="main-content">
    Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">
      Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">
          Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">Testing<br _ngcontent-c0="">
  </div>
</div>
</app-root>

</body></html>
```

Comment: Where's the problem example? Nobody is going to guess at what is different. See [mcve]

Comment: The problem example would need to be created in a new Angular project. Not sure if I can do this through a web snippet. So I am hoping someone can either place the snippet in an existing angular project that they have or create a new one real fast and pop it in to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Result in browser is still just html and css. All easily copied from browser dev tools

Comment: @charlietfl Thank you for the advice, post is updated.

Answer (score 1):

You can't style the `<body>` tag from CSS added to components with the default view encapsulation `ViewEncapsulation.emulated`. 
If you want to style parts outside your Angular application add the CSS to `index.html`.

As a hack you can disable view encapsulation by setting

```
@Component({
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.none,
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this info. Does this apply even if I use the outer level Styles.css file?

Comment: Does what apply? What is outer level Styles.css file?

Comment: I believe the Angular CLI adds this to the src (root) folder of the project. The comment at the top of the file is the following: /* You can add global styles to this file, and also import other style files */ I figured this would be the perfect place for html, body code.

Comment: Just check where it's added. If it's added to `index.html` directly then you can style the body element, if it is added to a component style (these styles get the `_ngcontent-c0` attributes added to the selector), then it's added to the component. I'm not using Angular CLI.

Comment: Well I put the body, html code in a styles tag in the head of index.html and still the same problem. It has to be some other feature that comes standard in Angular that is messing this up. If you look at my angular snippet html it seems like there are a bunch of JS imports at the bottom.

Comment: I don't think there is anything from Angular that messes it up.